# Laravel: Eliminar registros en cascada | Relación uno a muchos

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, blade

Sigo por acá abusando de sus conocimientos en Laravel ;).
Esta vez lo que necesito es eliminar en cascada en base a la relación de uno a muchos entre estas dos tablas:

- YEGUAS:
- id
- nombre
- edad

.

- EXAMENES:
- id
- yeguas_id
- diagnostico

.

La relación, obviamente, es que una YEGUA puede tener muchos EXAMENES.

En web.php tengo:

```
Route::get('/yeguas_list', 'YeguasController@yeguas_list')->name('yeguas_list');
Route::post('/delete_yegua', 'YeguasController@delete_yegua')->name('delete_yegua');
```

En la vista yeguas_list.blade.php tengo este enlace:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{$yegua->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Eliminar Yegua</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <p>¿Estas segur@ que quieres eliminar a {{$yegua->nombre_yegua}}?</p>
    </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('delete_yegua') }}">
   <input type="hidden" id="" name="id" value="{{$yegua->id}}">
   @csrf
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Si</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Tengo esto en el controlador YeguasController.php:

```
public function delete_yegua(Request $request){
   $yeguas = Yegua::find($request->id);
   $yeguas->delete();
   return back()->with('msg', "¡Yegua eliminada!");
}
```

Pero, el problema es que si elimina la YEGUA pero los EXAMENES correspondientes a esta no.

Gracias de antemano por leer y ayudarme.

Saludos.

Comment: Muestra por favor tu migración de la tabla que tiene la llave foranea

Comment: El proyecto me fue entregado sin migraciones, tengo la BD que importe y la tabla YEGUAS tiene: (id | int(11) | UNSIGNED) - (nombre | varchar(255)) - (edad | int(11))... Por otro lado la tabla EXAMENES tiene: (id | int(11) | UNSIGNED) - (yeguas_id | int(11)) - (diagnostico | longtext)

Comment: Si tienes definida la relación `examenes()` en el modelo Yegua puedes hacer `$yeguas->examenes()->delete();` antes de `$yeguas->delete();`. No es tan eficiente como hacerlo a nivel BD pues son dos consultas, pero funcionaría.

Comment: Gracias amigo @porloscerrosΨ, funciono perfecto... Ya he ido aprendiendo lo basico por acá gracias a tu ayuda y la de todos... Apenas me ponga a tiro voy a colaborar con esta comunidad, es de gran ayuda!!!

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas sencillo es utilizar la clausula ON DELETE CASCADE en la clave foranea (yeguas_id) de la tabla EXAMENES.

Con ello te olvidas de programar codigo, el motor de base de datos hace todo.

Primero deberas eliminar la clave foranea (si es que lo tiene ) y luego añadir con la sentencia.

```
alter table EXAMENES add foreign key YEGUAS_ID references YEGUAS(ID) on DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score -1):

Como alternativa, si por alguna razón no puedes modificar la BD como te lo sugiere la respuesta de @Aritz Ezkiaga, que sería lo más eficiente, puedes hacerlo a nivel aplicación.

Si tienes definida la relación `examenes()` en el modelo `Yegua`:

- Opción 1

En el Controlador puedes hacer `$yeguas->examenes()->delete()`; antes de `$yeguas->delete();` (lo hará solo cuando elimines un `Yegua` a través de este controlador):

```
public function delete_yegua(Request $request){
   $yegua = Yegua::find($request->id);
   $yegua->examenes()->delete();
   $yegua->delete();
   return back()->with('msg', "¡Yegua eliminada!");
}
```

- Opción 2

En el modelo, en el evento `deleting` (lo hará siempre que elimines un `Yegua`):

```
class Yegua extends Model
{
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($yegua) {
             $yegua->examenes()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

En principio digo que no es tan eficiente como hacerlo a nivel BD pues son dos consultas, pero funcionaría.

Pero agregaría que este enfoque te va a ayudar a desacoplar la "Lógica de Negocio" de la "Infraestructura/Persistencia".

Comment: Sería interesante que quien dió el voto negativo argumente, el por qué esta respuesta no es útil ¯\_(ツ)_/¯